# In which state do you pay taxes for money made on house sale?

Tags: united-states, taxes, real-estate, state-income-tax

I live in NJ but work in NY, so I file NY and NJ state returns.
I also sold a house in MD. Since that house was rented for a year when I did not live there, I need to pay taxes on a portion of the capital gain I made reselling it.

My understanding is that since the house was in MD, though I did not live in MD and had no income there, I need to pay state taxes on the percentage of the capital gain that is federally taxable (instead of adding it to my NJ income).

Am I correct? Do I have also to file MD taxes?

Comment: To which state were you paying the taxes you earned from the rental?

Answer (score 1):

1. Be aware that if you lived in the house for 2 of the last 5 years, you may deduct $250,000 on your capital gains ($500,000 if married and you both lived there).
2. If you have claimed depreciation on this property in the last five years, that will be treated as income, which will mean paying both New Jersey and Maryland income tax.  You should be able to deduct all Maryland income tax paid from your New Jersey income tax.

Comment: Even if I lived for 2 of the last 5 years, if the house was rented at all for any period, you need to pay a percentage of those capital gains equal to the percentage of the time it was rented vs the time owed. For example, if I owned it for 10 years and rented for a year, and the capital gain is 50,000, 5,000 is taxable. So, #1 in your answer is actually incorrect.

Comment: @user can you cite that?

Comment: @user IRS Publication 523 does not mention anything about rental property in regards to the usability and residence tests. See https://www.irs.gov/publications/p523#en_US_2017_publink100011707

Comment: @Magua A rental property is an investment, not your main residence. The $250,000 can be used for your main residence, not for a rental.

Comment: Business or Rental Use of Home

This section applies only if you used a portion of your home for business or rental purposes during your ownership. This type of usage may affect your gain or loss calculations. For more information about using any part of your home for business or as a rental property, see Pub. 587, Business Use of Your Home, and Pub. 527, Residential Rental Property.

Comment: @user 527 and 587 refer to rental and business income, not sale of the property.  OP also specified that he lives for 2 of the 5 years in the property, qualifying it under the eligibility test linked.

Comment: @Magua Read the whole thing: "This type of usage may affect your gain or loss calculation". You need to pay a percentage of your gain proportional to how long you used your home not for personal use but as an investment.

Comment: @user Can you kindly point me to where that is actually specified?

Comment: @Magua try looking here: https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i4797. I think the relevant part is: "the exclusion may not apply to the part of the gain that is allocated to any period after December 31, 2008, during which the property was not used as your principal residence". So it looks like if you rented the home before 2008 you might be right, but I think after 2008 I am correct.

Comment: That is new information to me, and so did some more digging.  Section 121 ( https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/121 ) went into effect January 1, 2009, and changed what could be qualified; that's the reason for your 4797 citation.  Section 121(b)(5)(C)(ii)(I)  specifically exempts any portion of the previous five years after the last time the owner lived there from being considered nonqualified for the purposes of the $250,000/$500,000 deduction..

Comment: So, if I understand the code @Magua quoted correctly, if OP lived rented the house one year, lived there for two, and rented for another two, he'd be able to claim the exemption for four years (the two he was living there and the two after), does that match your reading @magua?

Comment: @Magua Sorry, I never saw your answer. I ended up using a tax software and it did indeed make me pay some taxes on the money I made selling the house. Are you suggesting that I may have paid taxes I should not have paid?

Comment: Kevin: Yes, that is my reading. 

@user Can you go into more detail about what taxes were paid?

Comment: @Magua As I mentioned, I used some tax software. When I entered the details about my house sale it asked me if it had been rented after 2009 (it was, for a little over a year) and, despite the fact I had lived there the rest of the time since 2006 (when I bought it) I ended up paying about 10% (don't have the exact amount right now with me) of the money earned from the sale.

Comment: If you can find the form in the actual return, I would be interested in your numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Go through the process of determining if the gain is taxable on the federal forms. Even if there is no gain, there is likely to be a recapturing of the depreciation from the time the property was a rental property.

Then see if those lines/schedules transfer to the Maryland forms. I suspect they do. If so, you will have to file a final tax form in Maryland. The state of Maryland wants their portion because it is Maryland sourced income. They don't want that money to go to NY or NJ.